# iPhone App Distribution

Tags: iphone, app-store

is it possible to distribute an App via the App Store for free, in which You can only log in if you are using an extern charged Service

Answer (score 3):

I would say yes if I understand your question correctly. You just need to make the users login through your app on iphone and check to make sure they are member of this external charged service you talk about.

Comment: The Spotify app is a good example - the app is free, but you have to log in with a Premium account in order to actually use it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You will want to set up a test account so that the Apple App Review team can log in to your app and test it when you submit for approval.